# Data are not being downloaded after migrate to androidx

Tags: android-room, android-livedata, androidx, global-scope

After migrating to androidx, my room repositories based on LiveData and GlobalScope.launch stopped working.

I changed GlobalScope.launch to GlobalScope.async, because i got exception with observeForever (but I event don't use this method).

```
        val success = MediatorLiveData<SomeDataModel>()
        try {
            GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {
                success.addSource(myDao.getAll()) {
                    it?.let {
                        success.postValue(it)
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return success
    }

I want to point that before migrating to androidX this code worked.
```

Answer (score 0):

Code inside an async block does not execute until you `await` it somewhere else. If you're coming from a JavaScript world, this will surprise you because in JavaScript, `async` code executes before it's ever `await`ed.